# Action Script 3. How to disable all keyboard keys

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, keyboard, key

I'm creating flash game, where is needed only mouse to play. I need to disable all keyboard keys, but I can't do it successful.

I don't understand really how to make it, I need to removeEventListeners from all objects or for buttons? Maybe here is method to disable all keys? For example I tried this, but not working:

```
myButton1.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, blindKeyboard);
myButton1.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, blindKeyboard);
myButton2.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, blindKeyboard);
myButton2.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, blindKeyboard);

function blindKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in ActionScript 3, you do not put keyboard event listeners on objects, but on the stage.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressedDown);
```

Secondly, did you even set an event listener for the keyboard? Because unless you have, the game shouldn't take any keyboard command. You need to add an event listener to it.

Or do you mean the player shouldn't be able to enter anything in an input text field? Then how about using this?

```
inputField.maxChars=0;
```

Maximum number of characters set to zero, meaning they can't enter anything.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I mean, I need to make that players shouldn't be able to click any keys. For now they can use arrows / tab / space / enter keys and they can easly win the game. I need disable these functions.

Comment: and I did that before with sage, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: CLICK keys? You mean press, right? And what's "sage"? And uhm, did you actually program this game? Because if you haven't added a keyboard event listener, the player definitely shouldn't be able to move. Flash Player will simply not care about whether some key is pressed unless you specifically tell it to press a key. Ctrl-F your code for an addEventListener. It MUST be there. If you really don't understand why the player is able to move through pressing keys, would you mind showing me your code?

Comment: This doesn't work    `stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, blindKeyboard);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, blindKeyboard);`

Comment: `function blindKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}`

Comment: I'm not telling you to add code, I'm telling you to find whatever event listener there is in your code and remove it. You don't need to add anything to disable keyboard support in your game. You just need to remove what you must have added. As I told you, ActionScript does NOT care about any key pressed unless you give it an event listener. Remove the listener and you remove the problem.

Comment: In my code isn't any KeyboardListeners, this is "bug" I can't use any key, but after I click "Tab" key, first button gets "Yellow border" and I can use arrows (left, right, up, down) for select other buttons, cards and I can click "space" button to choose It.

Comment: Ooooh, now THAT's clear! What you're looking for is the .tabChildren property. It's a property for a parent. It defines whether you're able to select its children with Tab. I don't know if it cascades down (affects all grandchildren and great-grandchildren) or not, but try setting it to false on your stage, or on your main containing MovieClip, or on your problem elements' immediate parent. someMovieClip.tabChildren=false; There is also .tabEnabled, that you put directly on the child, in case you want only some elements to leave the tab focus order.

Comment: Reference for .tabChildren http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#tabChildren ----- Reference for .tabEnabled http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabEnabled

Answer (score 1):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, blindKeyboard);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, blindKeyboard);

function blindKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

This should work. Keep in mind however that some keys can't be turned off and will keep a default behavior (for instance, if you're publishing your game in a browser page, you won't be able to prevent the escape key from quitting the fullscreen mode).
More information is required if you need more help...feel free to answer me and add more details to your question if you still need some.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I not understand what happening, I can use arrow keys, tab, space buttons, I tried this add, remove listeners, nothing helps...

Comment: This is "bug" I can't use any key, but after I click "Tab" key, first button gets "Yellow border" and I can use arrows (left, right, up, down) for select other buttons, cards and I can click "space" button to choose It

Comment: I see...This is a focus problem. When you use the tab key, the focus switches to the button which then appears with a yellow border.
Not sure what is wrong with the rest of your code, maybe if you post more of it i'll be able to help ;)